# Scatter plot created using for loop. Need help using cmap and hold feature

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code that is extracting information from files and plotting this information on a scatterplot. The plot is created, but now I would like each point to have a different color so that the x-axis goes from a blue to a red hue ('bwr' cmap). Essentially, every time the program loops, I need a different colored marker. I can not figure out how to make this work. I am trying to use a counter, but that is also not working.

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
i=0
for path in paths:
     files = glob.glob ('./' + path + 'filename')
     print(files)
     for file in files
          for filtername in filterlist:
               hdu = fits.open(file)
               # Extract information in this loop
               x=xdata
               y=ydata
     ax1.set_xlabel('x-axis')
     ax1.set_ylabel('y-axis')
     ax1.scatter(xdata, ydata, c=i, cmap='bwr')
     plt.hold(True)
savefig('plot')
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way obtaining such a plot within a for loop? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html):

> cmap : Colormap, optional, default: None
>   A Colormap instance or registered colormap name. **cmap is only used if c is an array of floats.** If None, defaults to rc image.cmap.

If I understood correctly what you want, try to edit the line:

```
ax1.scatter(xdata, ydata, c=i, cmap='bwr')
```

in

```
ax1.scatter(xdata, ydata, c=xdata, cmap='bwr')
```

and should work.

Here a very simple sample code to show it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
xdata = np.linspace(1, 10, 100)
ydata = xdata**2

plt.scatter(xdata, ydata, c=xdata, cmap='bwr')
ax1.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('y-axis')
fig1.savefig('plot.jpg')
```

The resulting image is:

[image]